# If a Nagios script takes keyword instead of positional arguments, how would you setup Nagios for it?

Tags: nagios

**# FROM THE COMMAND LINE THIS WORKS (note the arguments to "-a"):**

```
 ./check_nrpe -p 12490 -H 10.246.107.167 -t 120 -c simple_add2 -a 4  56
```

**## because NSC.INI has this:**

```
simple_add2=perl scripts\simple_add2.plx -m $ARG1$ -n $ARG2$
```

**# BUT the "-n" argument is optional, so I want to be able to call simple_add2 either way:**

### like this:

```
./check_nrpe -p 12490 -H 10.246.107.167 -t 120 -c simple_add2 -a -m 4  -n 56
```

### or like this:

```
 ./check_nrpe -p 12490 -H 10.246.107.167 -t 120 -c simple_add2 -a -m 4
```

**# HERE IS MY CURRENT COMMAND AND SERVICE:**

I do not want to create two different commands and two different External Scripts listings for the same command simply because I want to call it with or without the -n argument... just imagine if I wrote a script with several optional keyword arguments. The explosion of commands and External Scripts would be combinatoric.

```
define command {
       command_name  add_numbers_service
       command_line  $USER1$/check_nrpe -p 12490 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u -t 90 -c \
simple_add_pln -a $ARG1$ $ARG2$
}

define service {
  host_name             awswinserver
  service_description   simple-addition-test
  check_command         add_numbers_service!4!5

 use                   generic-service
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I only mention this since I didn't realise it for the longest time; $ARG1$ can have quite a lot of stuff in it.  Have you considered:

```
simple_add2=perl scripts\simple_add2.plx -m $ARG1$

define command {
       command_name  add_numbers_service
       command_line  $USER1$/check_nrpe -p 12490 -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -u -t 90 -c \
simple_add_pln -a $ARG1$
}

define service {
  host_name             awswinserver
  service_description   simple-addition-test-1
  check_command         add_numbers_service!4
  use                   generic-service
}


define service {
  host_name             awswinserver
  service_description   simple-addition-test-2
  check_command         add_numbers_service!4 -n 56
  use                   generic-service
}
```

Comment: so, basically adding spaces in your argument alleviates the need for optional args. interesting

Comment: this doesn't really work in Centreon because $ARGn$ wraps values in single quotes...